# how to read a specific csv line vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops

ask permission,
I created a bot to input data to the web using vb.net and selenium.
Retrieve data from csv .
How to retrieve data from csv as needed, for example, there are 100 rows, only 30-50 rows are taken, for example. The loop code should not be looped at all.

```
 Dim textFieldParser As TextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser(TextBox1.Text) With
                {
                    .TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited,
                    .Delimiters = New String() {","}
                }

        drv = New ChromeDriver(options)
        While Not textFieldParser.EndOfData
            Try
                Dim strArrays As String() = textFieldParser.ReadFields()
                Dim name As String = strArrays(0)
                Dim alamat As String = strArrays(1)
                Dim notlp As String = strArrays(2)
                drv.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL")
                Dim Nm = drv.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input"))
                Nm.SendKeys(name)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
            Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")

                End Try
        End While
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to read one specific line or a specific range of lines? Please update your question (don't just add a comment) and make that clear because you seem to be contradicting yourself at the moment.

Comment: Also, please don't add irrelevant tags. This question has nothing to do with VBScript. You'd probably know that if you had read the tag description, as you should have.

Comment: You cannot avoid reading every line up to the last one you want. If you want to ignore a particular number of lines when using a `TextFieldParser` then use a `for` loop to call `ReadLine` that many times, thus reading and discarding that many lines. You then call `ReadFields` for each line you want. If that's one line, just call it once. If it's a specific number of lines then, again, use a `for` loop to call `ReadFields` that many time to read and process that many lines.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I mean like that , thank you very much .  sorry i'm newbie to vb .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using `TextFieldParser` to read one specific line and a specific range of lines. Note that I am using zero-based indexes for the lines. You can adjust as required if you want to use 1-based line numbers.

```vb
Public Function GetLine(filePath As String, index As Integer) As String()
    Using parser As New TextFieldParser(filePath) With {.Delimiters = {","}}
        Dim linesDiscarded = 0

        Do Until linesDiscarded = index
            parser.ReadLine()
            linesDiscarded += 1
        Loop

        Return parser.ReadFields()
    End Using
End Function

Public Function GetLines(filePath As String, startIndex As Integer, count As Integer) As List(Of String())
    Using parser As New TextFieldParser(filePath) With {.Delimiters = {","}}
        Dim linesDiscarded = 0

        Do Until linesDiscarded = startIndex
            parser.ReadLine()
            linesDiscarded += 1
        Loop

        Dim lines As New List(Of String())

        Do Until lines.Count = count
            lines.Add(parser.ReadFields())
        Loop

        Return lines
    End Using
End Function
```

Simple loops to skip and to take lines.